# Cannot splat an Array into function's arguments that accepts varargs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have tried to make a function that can enrich a given `DataFrame` with a "session" column using a window function. So I need to use `partitionBy` and `orderBy`.

```
val by_uuid_per_date = Window.partitionBy("uuid").orderBy("year","month","day")

// A Session = A day of events for a certain user. uuid x (year+month+day)

val enriched_df = df
.withColumn("session", dense_rank().over(by_uuid_per_date))
.orderBy("uuid","timestamp")
.select("uuid","year","month","day","session")
```

This works perfectly, but when I try to make a function that encapsulates this behavior :

PS: I used the `_*` splat operator.

```
def enrich_with_session(df:DataFrame, 
                        window_partition_cols:Array[String], 
                        window_order_by_cols:Array[String],
                        presentation_order_by_cols:Array[String]):DataFrame={

  val by_uuid_per_date = Window.partitionBy(window_partition_cols: _*).orderBy(window_order_by_cols: _*)

  df.withColumn("session", dense_rank().over(by_uuid_per_date))
  .orderBy(presentation_order_by_cols:_*)
  .select("uuid","year","month","mday","session")
}
```

I get the following error:

> notebook:6: error: no `: _*' annotation allowed here
>   (such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)
>     val by_uuid_per_date = Window.partitionBy(window_partition_cols: _*).orderBy(window_order_by_cols: _*)

Comment: Probably `partitionBy` does not expect a varidic arguments. But is simple overloaded to variations of one, two, etc arguments. Try checking the documentation or the source code.

Answer (score 1):

***partitionBy*** and ***orderBy*** are expecting **Seq[Column]** or 
**Array[Column]** as arguments, see below:

```
val data = Seq(
(1,99),
(1,99),
(1,70),
(1,20)
).toDF("id","value")

data.select('id,'value, rank().over(Window.partitionBy('id).orderBy('value))).show()

val partitionBy: Seq[Column] = Seq(data("id"))
val orderBy: Seq[Column] = Seq(data("value"))
data.select('id,'value, rank().over(Window.partitionBy(partitionBy:_*).orderBy(orderBy:_*))).show()
```

So in this case, your code should looks like this:

```
  def enrich_with_session(df:DataFrame,
                      window_partition_cols:Array[String],
                      window_order_by_cols:Array[String],
                      presentation_order_by_cols:Array[String]):DataFrame={

val window_partition_cols_2: Array[Column] = window_partition_cols.map(df(_))
val window_order_by_cols_2: Array[Column] = window_order_by_cols.map(df(_))
val presentation_order_by_cols_2: Array[Column] = presentation_order_by_cols.map(df(_))

val by_uuid_per_date = Window.partitionBy(window_partition_cols_2: _*).orderBy(window_order_by_cols_2: _*)

df.withColumn("session", dense_rank().over(by_uuid_per_date))
  .orderBy(presentation_order_by_cols_2:_*)
  .select("uuid","year","month","mday","session")
```

}